# Javascript mixin issues - base is not a constructor

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, requirejs, mixins

I ran into an interesting issue while trying to create a mixin for a 3rd party JS script. I created the mixin in the normal way with my `requirejs-config.js` like this:

```
let config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Amasty_Storelocator/js/location-view': {
                'Amasty_Storelocator/js/location-view-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

And my mixin file like this:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'domReady!'
], function($) {
    "use strict";
    return function (widget) {
        $.widget('mage.amLocationPage', widget, {
            initializeGallery: function () {
                $('[data-amlocator-js="locator-gallery"]').slick({
                    infinite: false,
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                    slidesToScroll: 1
                });
            }
        });
        return $.mage.amLocationPage;
    }
});
```

But when doing this i get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: base is not a constructor

This is pointing the jQuery Ui widget file that looks to define any widget with `$.widget = function (name, base, prototype)`.

When i change the file like this:

```
$.widget('mage.amLocationPage', $.mage.amLocationPage, {}
```

The error goes away and my mixin works just fine. But i don't know why this is happening. I have used plenty of mixins without `$.mage.amLocationPage` before. Any ideas why this happening in this use case?

Comment: Code `let config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Amasty_Storelocator/js/location-view': {
                'Amasty_Storelocator/js/location-view-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};`seem wrong .  Mixin files exist at same modules `Amasty_Storelocator`?

Comment: That's what i thought too. But the file loads fine. In the `pub/static` folder, the two files sit next to each other and don't seem to have an issue. My thought was that the mixin didn't "generate" that correct "import" for the widget with this requirejs config. But with all the variations i tried, this config seems correct.